# Using regular expression to validate colon separated inputs

Tags: java, regex

I'm reading in a file for a Java application which has data separated by colons in the format:

```
test : test : 0 : 0
```

Where the first two segments are names of something and the last two are digits.

The match should fail if the input is not formatted in that exact way above (aside from the data being different)

```
test : test : 0 : 0 -----> pass
: test: 0 : 0       -----> fail
0 : test : 0 : test -----> fail
test test : 0 : 0   -----> fail
```

So the match will fail if there are any segments omitted, if the digits and words do not appear where they should, i.e. `word : word : digit : digit`, and there has to be 3 colons and 4 segments no more no less as above.

This is where I have gotten so far but it's not quite right:

```
^\D+(?:\s\:\s\w+)*$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex like

```
^[a-zA-Z]+\s*:\s*[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s*:\s*\d+){2}$
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string (implicit in `String#matches`)
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters
- `\s*:\s*` - a `:` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters
- `(?:\s*:\s*\d+){2}` - two occurrences of `:` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces and then 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string (implicit in `String#matches`)

**NOTE**: If there must be an obligatory single space between the items, you need to replace `\s*` with `\s`. To match 1 or more whitespaces, `\s*` must be turned into `\s+`.

In Java, you may write it as

```
s.matches("[a-zA-Z]+\\s*:\\s*[a-zA-Z]+(?:\\s*:\\s*\\d+){2}")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FCeZuB/2)

Comment: Almost perfect but I realized a problem I didn't outline in the original question that I just discovered when testing that the first two words may have numerous spaces in them but this should still pass e.g. "test test : test test test : digit : digit" and the white spaces either side of the colon are obligatory thank you for specifying how to fix that.

Comment: @ThomasMorton I think you want to make sure there is at least 1 letter in the first 2 fields, right? Then use `s.matches("[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\\s]*:\\s*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\\s]*(?:\\s*:\\s*\\d+){2}")`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FCeZuB/3). You might use `"[a-zA-Z\\s]+:[a-zA-Z\\s]+(?:\\s*:\\s*\\d+){2}"`, but then, the first two fields [could be blank](https://regex101.com/r/xIGfQm/1).

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `String#matches` on each line, with the following pattern:

```
[a-z]+ : [a-z]+ : [0-9]+ : [0-9]+
```

For example:

```
String line = "test : test : 0 : 0";
if (line.matches("[a-z]+ : [a-z]+ : [0-9]+ : [0-9]+")) {
    System.out.println("Found a match");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go (demo at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/EPSIzI/1)):

```
[a-zA-Z]+\s+:\s+[a-zA-Z]+\s+:\s+\d+\s+:\s+\d+
```

Explanation:

- `[a-zA-Z]+` stands for 1 or more letters (`+` is the modifiers allowing to match the previous statement at least once
- `\s+` stands for 1 or more
- `:` is the `:` character, literally
- `\d+` stands for at least one digit (remove the `+` to match one digit exactly)

Finally, compose those parts according to your needs. You might want to make the Regex make stricter replacing the `\s+` with only one empty space .

Validate the String using the method [`String::matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) (don't forget to use two slashes `\\`):

```
boolean isValid = string.matches("[a-zA-Z]+\\s+:\\s+[a-zA-Z]+\\s+:\\s+\\d+\\s+:\\s+\\d+");
```